# Type Class From Subset Of Recursive Type Class (Or Type From Recursive Type)

Tags: haskell, recursion, typeclass, abstract-data-type

How do I create a recursive type class which behaves like another recursive type class but has not as many instances as the "parent" class?

Here is an example:

```
data Atom = Atom
data (Formula a) => Negation a = Negation a

class Formula a where
instance Formula Atom where
instance (Formula a) => Formula (Negation a) where

class SubFormula a where
instance SubFormula Atom where
```

That code compiles just fine but when I add a function which converts an instance of the super type class to one of the sub type class

```
formulaToSubFormula :: (Formula a, SubFormula b) => a -> b
formulaToSubFormula _ = Atom
```

I get an error

```
test.hs:12:25:
    Could not deduce (b ~ Atom)
    from the context (Formula a, SubFormula b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 formulaToSubFormula :: (Formula a, SubFormula b) => a -> b
      at test.hs:12:1-28
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            formulaToSubFormula :: (Formula a, SubFormula b) => a -> b
          at test.hs:12:1
    In the expression: Atom
    In an equation for `formulaToSubFormula':
        formulaToSubFormula _ = Atom
```

---

My original intent was to do this with normal types but with type classes the problem seems more approachable and generally more flexible.

For example:

```
data Formula = Atom | Negation Formula | Conjunction Formula Formula
data SubFormula = Atom | Negation SubFormula
```

---

## Edit

To clarify what I try to achieve: I want to verify on the type level that an operation on the input type will return only a subset of that type as the result.

Extended example (propositional logic; no valid Haskell syntax):

```
data Formula = Atom
             | Negation Formula
             | Disjunction Formula Formula
             | Implication Formula Formula
data SimpleFormula = Atom
                   | Negation SimpleFormula
                   | Disjunction SimpleFormula SimpleFormula

-- removeImplication is not implemented correctly but shows what I mean
removeImplication :: Formula -> SimpleFormula
removeImplication (Implication a b) = (Negation a) `Disjunction` b
removeImplication a = a
```

At a later point I may have a formula in the conjunctive normal form (no valid Haskell syntax)

```
data CNF = CNFElem
         | Conjunction CNF CNF
data CNFElem = Atom
             | Negation Atom
             | Disjunction CNFElem CNFElem
```

Therefore I need a tool to represent this hierarchy.

Comment: Note that in the `removeImplication` plan you are only removing the outermost `Implication` constructor.  `removeImplication (Negation (Implication x y))` would be `(Negation (Implication x y))`.  A simple solution is just to have two types `Formula` and, say, `NormalForm` and a function `toNormalForm`, which goes through complex formulas and recursively converts Implications to the appropriate NormalForm, no?  I think we still need to know more about where you are going with this.

Comment: @applicative: The `removeImplication` function is only there to show what I mean. The thing is, `NormalForm` is a subset of `Formula` and that's why I'm looking for a way to share this subset between both types.

Comment: It is still opaque what your wider purpose is; for example, whether it would be worth taking a route of one of the sorts `stephen tetley` mentions.  A data type definition, especially a recursive one, is like a miniature language. You are considering several little languages and their relationships; why shouldn't these relations be expressed by *functions between the types*? If `L1` and `L2` are types then the types `L1 -> L2` and `L2 -> L1` are the types of relations between them, to put it crudely.

Comment: I take it you are aware that in  `data CNFElem` and `data CNF` you need to wrap the first 'constructor'. As it stands each is a type that has already been defined, `Atom` and `CNFElem` respectively, and cant be a constructor of the type you are defining. So you need `data CNFElem = CNFAtom Atom | ...` and `data CNF = CNFElt CNFElem`.  This holds for most of the type definitions earlier in the query as well.

Comment: @applicative: I never thought about the different formula/data types as different languages because every `CNF-Formula` is a valid `Formula` (although not every `Formula` is a valid `CNF-Formula`). Hence I tried to visualize this 'inheritance' via the type system.

Comment: Stephen Tetley's suggestion is interesting and I will consider using his approach.

Regarding the wrong data definition: You are right, I just wanted show the structure but intermingled it with Haskell's syntax.

Comment: "Every CNF-Formula is a valid Formula (although not every Formula is a valid CNF-Formula)." -- Well, this is to say that you could use `isFormula` and `isCNFFormula` as a predicate of `String`s, or else use `isCNFFormula` as a predicate of `Formula`s. It latently rejects a representation of *both* as types, that is, as something presupposed by the representation of its occupants. "All B's are C's" presupposes that there is a common type, say A, and we can affirm or deny "is a B" and "is a C" of A's -- or else that B is the underlying type and the predicate "is C" is defined in relation to it.

Comment: I meant to add to the ones `stephen tetley` mentioned the paper [Data Types a la Carte](www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~wss/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf).  Here is a module containing some of the material http://hpaste.org/46175/data_types_a_la_carte. I can't remember where I came by it.

Comment: The relevant material precedes line 124. His `Val` corresponds to your `Atom` sort of, his `Add` and `Mul` correspond to your `Disjunction` and `Implication` (we need negation in here). `(:+:)` adds one ingredient to another.  So first we have a `data Val e = Val Int` (note the unused parameter); then `data Add e = Add e e`, a sort of diagonalizer, also a Functor. Together they give us `Val :+: Add`, another Functor. Then we add `data Mul e = Mul e e` and can consider `(Val :+: Add) :+: Mul`, a new Functor instance.

Comment: `Expr` takes the fixed point of any of these, thus Expr (Val :+: Add), a single type, has sums and sums of sums etc. (The "leaves" are `Int`s due to the definition of `Val`) `Expr ((Val :+: Add) :+: Mul)` represents sums, products, sums of products, etc. Finally, he multiparameter type class `(:<:)` then has some of the look of a 'subtype` relation, but note it relates Functors in the type system.  I haven't studied it for a while; it is difficult but very interesting and comparatively readable.

Comment: @applicative: The paper you mentioned is really interesting. But I, honestly, have no idea how to enforce a structure like a CNF (my last example). I would have to write `type CNF = Expr (Conjunction :+: Disjunction :+: Atom :+: Negation)` but that would allow arbitrary nesting of `Conjunction`s and `Disjunctions` although `Disjunction`s are not allowed to contain `Conjunction`s (the same for `Negation`s).

Comment: If I had to resort to using predicates like `isCNFFormula` anyway, then I could use a simple recursive data type in the first place as I couldn't determine the `Formula`'s structure from its type (which is the whole point, isn't it?). What am I missing? And BTW: thank you for your help - I already learned quite something from the paper and from playing around with the concept it describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to represent the nesting constraints in the data types is some kind of rule system via type classes like this:

```
data Formula t val = Formula val deriving Show

-- formulae of type t allow negation of values of type a

class Negatable t a
instance Negatable Fancy a
instance Negatable Normal a
instance Negatable NNF Atom
instance Negatable CNF Atom
instance Negatable DNF Atom

class Conjunctable t a
instance Conjunctable Fancy a
instance Conjunctable Normal a
instance Conjunctable NNF a
instance Conjunctable CNF a
instance Conjunctable DNF Atom
instance Conjunctable DNF (Negation a)
instance Conjunctable DNF (Conjunction a b)

---

negate :: (Negatable t a) => Formula t a -> Formula t (Negation a)
negate (Formula x) = Formula $ Negation x

conjunct :: (Conjunctable t a, Conjunctable t b)
         => Formula t a -> Formula t b -> Formula t (Conjunction a b)
conjunct (Formula x) (Formula y) = Formula $ Conjunction x y
```

The papers you mentioned, especially [Data types a la cart](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~wss/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf), were really helpful though.

Answer (score 2):

> converts an instance of the super type class to one of the sub type class

Haskell typeclasses don't work like this.

They don't provide coercions or subtyping. Your function returning an `Atom` can only be of `Atom` return type, since it returns an explicit constructor that builds `Atom` values.

For modelling expression languages like this, *algebraic data types* (or sometimes, *generalized algebraic data types*) are the overwhelmingly preferred option:

```
data Proposition
    = LITERAL Bool
    | ALL (Set Proposition)
    | ANY (Set Proposition)
    | NOT Proposition
```

which can be made arbitrarily expressive with parameterized types, or GADTs, depending on your application.

Answer (score 2):

I've made this an answer because it's quite long and I wanted formatting. Really, I'd consider it a comment as it's more of an opinion than a solution.

It looks like you are wanting extensible / modular syntax although you are phrasing your needs from the *general* to the *specific* - most writing about extensible syntax takes the other view and considers adding extra cases to make "small" syntax larger.

There are ways to achieve extensible syntax in Haskell e.g. the "Finally Tagless" style [1] or Sheard and Pasalic's two level types[2].

In practice, though, the "protocol" code to get modular syntax is complicated and repetitive and you lose nice features of regular Haskell data types, particularly pattern matching. You also lose a **lot** of clarity. This last bit is crucial - modular syntax is such a "tax" on clarity that it is rarely worth using. You are usually better off using data types that exactly match your current problem, if you need to extend them later you can edit the source code.

[1] http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/tagless/jfp.pdf

[2] http://homepage.mac.com/pasalic/p2/papers/JfpPearl.pdf

Comment: The two-level-type approach looks promising and I will have a deeper look at it. What the other paper describes seems too complicated for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that in `formulaToSubFormula _ = Atom`, the output is created with the `Atom` constructor, so it is always of type `Atom`, whereas the type signature declares it to be any type with a `SubFormula` instance.  One option is to add a function to the `SubFormula` class:

```
class SubFormula a where
  atom :: a

instance SubFormula Atom where
  atom = Atom

formulaToSubFormula :: (Formula a, SubFormula b) => a -> b
formulaToSubFormula _ = atom
```

Of course, if you will only have one instance of the subtype, you can dispense with the class entirely:

```
formulaToSubFormula2 :: Formula a => a -> Atom
```

Also note that

```
data (Formula a) => Negation a = Negation a
```

probably doesn't do what you want.  The intention is presumably that only `Formula a` types can be negated and will always have the `Formula` context available, but instead this means that any time you use a `Negation a` you will need to provide a `Formula a` context, even if it isn't used.  You can get the desired result by writing this with [GADT syntax](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt-style):

```
data Negation a where
  Negation :: Formula a => a -> Negation a
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that might be going on here, I doubt that any involves the introduction of type classes. (The fancy thing that might be in the offing here is a GADT.) The following is very simple-minded; it is just intended to get you to say what you want more clearly....

Here is a polymorphic type like the one you had originally. Since it is polymorphic you can use anything to represent the atomic formulas.

```
data Formula a = Atom a 
               | Negation (Formula a)    
               | Conjunction (Formula a) (Formula a) deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Here is a function that extracts all subformulas:

```
subformulas (Atom a) = [Atom a]
subformulas (Negation p) = Negation p : subformulas p
subformulas (Conjunction p q) = Conjunction p q : (subformulas p ++ subformulas q)
```

Here is a type to use if you aren't contemplating very many atomic propositions:

```
data Atoms = P | Q | R | S | T | U | V deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Here are some random helpers:

```
k p q = Conjunction p q
n p  = Negation p
p = Atom P
q = Atom Q
r = Atom R
s = Atom S

x --> y = n $ k x (n y)  -- note lame syntax highlighting

-- Main>  ((p --> q) --> q)
-- Negation (Conjunction (Negation (Conjunction (Atom P) (Negation (Atom Q)))) (Negation (Atom Q)))
-- Main> subformulas ((p --> q) --> q)
-- [Negation (Conjunction (Negation (Conjunction (Atom P) (Negation (Atom Q)))) (Negation (Atom Q))),
--     Conjunction (Negation (Conjunction (Atom P) (Negation (Atom Q)))) (Negation (Atom Q)),
--     Negation (Conjunction (Atom P) (Negation (Atom Q))),
--     Conjunction (Atom P) (Negation (Atom Q)),Atom P,
--     Negation (Atom Q),Atom Q,Negation (Atom Q),Atom Q]
```

Lets make Boolean Atoms!:

```
t = Atom True
f = Atom False

-- Main> t --> f
-- Main> subformulas ( t --> f)
-- [Negation (Conjunction (Atom True) (Negation (Atom False))),
--           Conjunction (Atom True) (Negation (Atom False)),      
--            Atom True,Negation (Atom False),Atom False]
```

Why not a simple evaluation function?

```
 eval :: Formula Bool -> Bool
 eval (Atom p) = p
 eval (Negation p) = not (eval p)
 eval (Conjunction p q) = eval p && eval q
```

a few random results:

```
 -- Main> eval (t --> f )
 -- False
 -- Main> map eval $ subformulas (t --> f)
 -- [False,True,True,True,False]
```

Added later: note that `Formula` is a `Functor` with an obvious instance that can be inferred by the GHC if you add Functor to the deriving clause and the language pragma `{-#LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor#-}`.  Then you can use any function `f :: a -> Bool` as an assignment of truth values:

```
-- *Main> let f p = p == P || p == R
-- *Main>  fmap f (p --> q)
-- Negation (Conjunction (Atom True) (Negation (Atom False)))
-- *Main> eval it
-- False
-- *Main>  fmap f ((p --> q) --> r)
-- Negation (Conjunction (Negation (Conjunction (Atom True) (Negation (Atom False)))) (Negation (Atom True)))
-- *Main> eval it
-- True
```